# angular 6 HttpInterceptor not firing

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to implement my out HttpErrorInterceptor to catch http errors coming back from the REST services in my angular 6 app, but it's not firing.  Below is my code, and I missing something/what am I doing wrong?

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log('interceptor works!');
                let errMsg = '';
                // Client Side Error
                if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                    errMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                } else {  // Server Side Error
                    errMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                }
                return throwError(errMsg);
            })
        );
}
```

}

app.module.ts

```
    providers: [
    , {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized one of my modules was also importing the HttpClientModule (in addition to my app.module.ts.  Once I removed that, it worked like a charm!